# Clearing all controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm clearing all the controls on a windows form with the following

```
form.Controls.Cast<dynamic>().ToList().ForEach(c =>
{
      switch (c)
      {
          case CheckBox t when c is CheckBox:
              c.Checked = false;
              break;
          case System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox t when c is System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox:
              c.Items.Clear();
              break;
          case CheckEdit t when c is CheckEdit:
              c.Checked = false;
              break;
          default:
              c.Text = "";
              break;
      }
});
```

I have to use `dynamic` because if I dont, I wont get the options for `Checked` and I also wont be able to clear any `items` in a combobox or list for that matter.
 Is there a neater way of achieving this? I'm using c# 7.3 which allows me to use the [when](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) keyword, I wasn't able to find how to do this with anything under 7.0, If there is something for under 7.0, what would it be?

Comment: Why are you seeking a way how to do it in C# 7.0 if you can use the latest 7.3?

Comment: ` If there is something for under 7.0, what would it be?`

Comment: Still, why? Why would someone want to use something older if he can do it much easier with the latest version?

Comment: work is still using 6.0

Comment: If so then your question is off-topic because it's unimplemented code.

Comment: You dont have to use dynamic. You could just cast the incoming type as what ever it is. (Which is what your when ... is calls do anyways. There are very few (maybe none) cases where you *need* to use Dynamic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're rather over-complicated this for yourself! A much better solution is to use the pattern matched results (which you are already creating (`t`)) (this requires C# 7.0 still, I believe).

```cs
foreach (Control c in form.Controls)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case CheckBox cb:
            cb.Checked = false;
            break;
        case ComboBox cb:
            cb.Items.Clear();
            break;
        case CheckEdit ce:
            ce.Checked = false;
            break;
        default:
            c.Text = "";
            break;
    }
}
```

- No dynamic here: `Text` is already a member of `Control`.
- Foreach loops are easier to read than `.Foreach` (in my opinion, at least; even if they are a bit funny underneath)
- Your original `ToList` was redundant: no need to cache a result you are going to stream immediately in single-threaded logic
- I've renamed `t` to something *slightly* less terrible; since they are very local variables indeed, I personally wouldn't worry to much about the names.
- Note that this code will also clear the text on labels, and buttons, and everything else... so it seems an odd thing to provide as a form-wide operation.

Comment: That does indeed look much nicer than what I have above even if I was using Linq. You're right your code does indeed still require 7.0 because its using pattern matching, I could be wrong, will need to investigate it. As for clearing everything, indeed this is the point, as part of the function, for an extension helper, our developers will have the option of what control(s) they want to clear, by control type or name and what controls they dont want to clear by control type of name, this will save them writing a method to just having one line.

Comment: There is no better solution than this one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should use recursive method to check all controls, even those nested in grouping controls like panels:

```
 public void ClearControls(Control parent)
        {
            foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
            {
                switch (c.GetType().ToString())
                {
                    case "CheckBox":
                        (c as CheckBox).Checked = false;
                        break;
                    case "ComboBox":
                        (c as ComboBox).Items.Clear();
                        break;
                    case "CheckEdit":
                        (c as CheckEdit).Checked = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        c.Text = "";
                        break;
                }

                ClearControls(c);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Consider checking against at least the type name instead of magic strings, the casts should ideally have clear checks to confirm they worked, and the var aa seems like it might not be needed?

Comment: You are right about the var aa i removed it already. Forgot to delete it before publishing thanks for let me know. Referring to 'magic string' I cannot use Name since switch is expecting constant value with version Framework 4.6.1 on which I tested out this solution.

Comment: This is actually worse than the  OP's solution. All those hardcoded magic-strings and casting with `as` :-o

Comment: But it works under 7.0, Dont get me wrong I can see VisualMelon's solution is better than this but problem is he needs C# v 7.0+ and this is alternative version for somebody who needs it under 7.0.